# What is apparent density?

Tags: definition, fluid-statics, density

For any floating body apparent weight and apparent density of body is zero.how.explain also explain what does apparent density meean.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you had a giant plastic bag that holds a cubic meter. Suppose the mass of the bag is $100$ g. If you weigh it, you measure a mass of $100$ g. (OK, you measure a weight of $0.98$ N, and convert to a mass of $100$ g.)

Suppose you open the bag and fill it with air. When you weigh it, you still find the mass is $100$ g. You might think that you should get a higher mass because there is air inside, and the mass of $1 m^3$ of air is about $1$ kg.

On the other hand, it is also obvious you don't get a different mass. The configuration with air inside the bag isn't much different than air outside.

You can repeat the same thing under water. $1 m^3$ of water has a mass of $1000$ kg. The mass is much bigger, but the result is the same. You can easily hold up the $1$ ton mass underwater, but not in air.

---

If you have $1$ kg of air with or without the bag, it floats. That is, gravity pulls down on it with a force of $9.8$ N, but the air around it pushes up with the same force. The net result is a total force of $0$ N on the air. If you figure out the mass of the air from the weight, you get $0$ kg. Air apparently has a density of $0 kg/m^3$.

This is because you have ignored the force of air pushing upward. If you counted only the force of gravity, you would get $9.8$ N, which corresponds to a mass of $1$ kg and the correct density of $1 kg/m^3$.

This makes a big difference for low density objects like air. But it isn't so much for higher density objects like water.

Suppose we have $1 m^3$ of water sitting in air. Gravity pulls down on the $1000$ kg mass with a force of $9800$ N. Air pushes up with a force of $9.8$ N. The total force is $0.1$ % less, $9790.2$ N. If you use that force to calculate the mass, you get $999$ kg. So if you ignore the upward force from air, you get an apparent weight and apparent density that are $0.1$ % too small. People generally ignore that unless they are interested in very precise measurements.

Comment: Didn't understood anything

Comment: Please explain briefly not in detail

Comment: Please explain in simple words in short

Answer (score 1):

Apparent weight is zero, because the downward force due to gravity is equal to the upward force of buoyancy, and these two cancel out.

IF one defines apparent density as apparent weight/volume, it would be 0, since the numerator is 0.

Some schoolbooks contain the statement you mentioned. I consider this usage of apparent density to be trivial and not so helpful. In a different context, apparent density means something completely different- the density of porous materials when measured by their mass and observed volume.